# Can 저 be used for abstract things?

Tags: vocabulary, word-usage

According to most simple explanations, the demonstrative 이 can be used to talk about real physical things close to the speaker, 그 for things nearer the listener, and 저 things far from both.

But 이 can also be used in a more abstract sense, e.g. 이 달 – 'this month', and so can 그 , e.g. 그와 같은 경우에는 – 'in a case like that'.

Can 저 ever used for abstract things, or is it always used for real objects? Would the thing indicated always have to be visible?

Answer (score 4):

저 can also be used for invisible things. In that case it is usually accompanied by 이 or 그. These words can be good examples: '이러쿵저러쿵', '이러저러하다.'

Answer (score 2):

> 이 : thing in small distance
>
> 저 : 1) lowering myself
>   2) thing in long distance
>
> 3) lowering a indicted person.
>
> 그 : indicated thing

2) 저 사람 우리 오빠야.

He is my brother.

(불난 집을 바라보면서) 저를 어째

(Seeing a house with fire) How do we deal that ?

이도 저도 아니다.

Even though we did something, there is no progress. (it is nothing).

저 번달 = 지 난달 = last month

3) A : C는 버릇이 없어

B : 저하고 싶은 데로 하라고 해.

A : C is rude

B : Don't mind C = Do not care the way C do